# Struggling with htaccess and regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I just can't get my head around the regex required for a URL rewrite.

I want the following :

```
http://domain.com/?hid=yv&v=0.1.4383
```

to rewrite to

```
http://domain.com/example/
```

All other pages should remain unchanged.
Anyone help me out and explain the regex required for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hid=yv&v=0\.1\.4383$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://domain.com/example/ [L,R]
```

Comment: That's almost it - but it caries the query string over to the new URL. Is there a way to stop that?